# Generating Javadoc in Maven does give errors because of proxy

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm trying to generate my javadoc using Maven to use in SpringFox Swagger.

When I generate the Javadoc using Maven I got an error like:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:javadoc (default) on project Spring-server: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "!"
 Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" -J-Dhttp.proxySet=true -J-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.5.5.5 -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 "-J-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=\"tst*\"" "-J-Dhttp.proxyUser=\"user\"" "-J-Dhttp.proxyPassword=\"pw with space !\"" @options @packages
```

How can I disable the proxy for generating Javadoc? I need the proxy to download all the dependencies but for generating the Javadoc itself it should not use any Proxy. So is it possible to disable the proxy for the javadoc maven Plugin?

My Maven javadoc settings looks like:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <doclet>springfox.javadoc.doclet.SwaggerPropertiesDoclet</doclet>
                            <docletArtifact>
                                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                                <artifactId>springfox-javadoc</artifactId>
                                <version>0.9.3</version>
                            </docletArtifact>
                            <additionalparam>
                                -classdir ${project.build.outputDirectory}
                            </additionalparam>
                            <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcepath>
                            <subpackages>com.atlascopco.ilm2</subpackages>
                            <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Where do these arguments come from in the first place?

Comment: I think my global Maven Settings. That's the only place where my proxy settings are saved.

Comment: Anything about this issue?

Comment: No.  This is where you start a bounty.

Comment: Had any luck finding the solution? I'm running into this now as well.

Comment: Didn't find any sollution for this. Also I'm not working for that client anymore so I cannot reproduce this.